# How to show region notification for iOS at most once a month?

Tags: swift, notifications, region

My app's deployment target is 10.0, and I used UNUserNotificationCenter to show region notification even when the app is closed/killed. But new mission is to show it at most once a month, though the user may enter the region more than once a month.

What I tried until now (which worked great) is...

```
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    content.title = "... Reminder"
    content.body = "Welcome to \(element.name). Please let us know how we can serve you and your loved ones, and we hope ... will simplify your visit here."
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    content.categoryIdentifier = "LOCATION_CAT"

    let centerCoordinate2D = element.location.coordinate
    let identifierName = element.name.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
    let region = CLCircularRegion(center: centerCoordinate2D, radius: 300, identifier: identifierName)
    region.notifyOnExit = false
    region.notifyOnEntry = true
    let trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region: region, repeats: true)

    // request = content + trigger
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "REGION \(element.name)", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    // add (or "schedule") request to center
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error: Error?) in

        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
```

But then, to let it happen at most once a month, I did the following:

```
    let centerCoordinate2D = element.location.coordinate
    let identifierName = element.name.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
    let region = CLCircularRegion(center: centerCoordinate2D, radius: 300, identifier: identifierName)
    region.notifyOnExit = true
    region.notifyOnEntry = true

    R.shared.appleLocationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
```

Also in AppDelegate.swift,

```
extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    // called when user Enters a monitored region
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {

        print("AppDelegate.locationManager( didEnterRegion ): called with region identifier: \(region.identifier)")

        if region is CLCircularRegion {
            // Do what you want if this information
            self.handleEvent(forRegion: region)
        }
    }

    func handleEvent(forRegion region: CLRegion) {

        // we save 'date' with "NOTIFICATION DATE request_identifier" as its key.
        let key = "NOTIFICATION DATE \(region.identifier)"
        let defaultValue = defaults.double(forKey: key)
        if defaultValue == 0 {
            print("AppDelegate.handleEvent(): need to show notification: no key")

            // set value first.
            defaults.set(Date().timeIntervalSince1970, forKey: key)

            showNotification(forRegion: region)

        } else {
            let diff = Date().timeIntervalSince(Date(timeIntervalSince1970: defaultValue))
            if  diff > 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 {
                print("AppDelegate.handleEvent(): need to show notification: diff > 30 days")

                // set value first.
                defaults.set(Date().timeIntervalSince1970, forKey: key)

                showNotification(forRegion: region)

            } else {
                // just pass.
                print("AppDelegate.handleEvent(): need NOT to show notification: diff: \(dot2(diff / 24 / 60)) mins")
            }
        }
    }

    func showNotification(forRegion region: CLRegion, message: String = "") {

        // customize your notification content
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "... Reminder"
        let hospitalName = region.identifier.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: " ")
        content.body = "Welcome to \(hospitalName). \(message) Please let us know how we can serve you and your loved ones, and we hope ... will simplify your visit here."
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

        // the actual trigger object
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0,
                                                        repeats: false)

        // notification unique identifier, for this example, same as the region to avoid duplicate notifications
        let identifier = "REGION \(hospitalName)"

        // the notification request object
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier,
                                            content: content,
                                            trigger: trigger)

        // trying to add the notification request to notification center
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in

            if let theError = error {
                print(theError.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }
```

with the following, still for the AppDelegate class:

```
let appleLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    self.appleLocationManager.delegate = self
    ...
}
```

I think there is error in the code, but it is not clear to me if the `locationManager( didExitRegion: )` is to be called even when the app is closed/killed - in which case appleLocationManager is not alive?

If I can't use `locationManager( didExitRegion: )` for this problem, what can I do to make the region notification happen at most once a month? I also know that there is a different type of trigger, UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger or UNLocationNotificationTrigger, and I wanted to use them somehow to solve this problem, but would there be any way to make it run some of my code even when the app is not running at all? If this is impossible to solve, isn't it enough to say that the region notification is too much restricted?

Answer (score 0):

Described as Apple's document, region monitoring with `CLLocationManager` wakes up your app if needed.

c.f. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/monitoring_the_user_s_proximity_to_geographic_regions

> Whenever the user crosses the boundary of one of your app's registered regions, the system notifies your app. If an iOS app is not running when the boundary crossing occurs, the system tries to launch it. An iOS app that supports region monitoring must enable the Location updates background mode so that it can be launched in the background.

You can also detect if the app is launched by regional notification with `UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey`.

> Boundary crossing notifications are delivered to your location manager's delegate object. Specifically, the location manager calls the locationManager(*:didEnterRegion:) or locationManager(*:didExitRegion:) methods of its delegate. If your app was launched, you must configure a CLLocationManager object and delegate object right away so that you can receive these notifications. To determine whether your app was launched for a location event, look for the UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey in the launch options dictionary.